# Can't seem to change the size of TextAreaFor() in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Below is my code and I set the values for columns and rows correctly or at least I thought I did but it won't change from the default size of the text area. What have I done wrong?

```
<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fullName, "Name:")
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.fullName, new { @cols="160", @rows="1" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fullName)
</div>
```

Comment: Just a quick note, you don't need the `@` for "cols" and "rows". You only need it when you are using a reserved word, such as `@class`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cols` and `rows` are relative to font size. height and width, also `line-height` and `letter-spacing` if explicitly set as well.

So use height width properties

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.fullName, new { @Style="height:400px; width:300px;" })
```